# blogging from within emacs

Tags: emacs, blogs

I would like to know what packages and tools to use to write blogs from within emacs. 
I mean packages to write and publish.
I 've seen a demo of that in textmate : http://blog.macromates.com/2006/blogging-from-textmate/

Is it possible to do the same in emacs?

Thank you very much.

Edit: I found a package in google code that serve blogging form emacs [e-blog](http://code.google.com/p/e-blog/)

I still don't get it why this thread is closed !!!! Not related to development!!???

Comment: I jsut found out ain google code to serve this purpose http://code.google.com/p/e-blog/

Comment: I blog from emacs at http://members.wolfram.com/billw/summa.  I write entries in muse-mode, then use its built-in pyblosxom cooperation to build a blog-style dir hierarchy.  The only problem is that pyblosxom rebuilds the entire blog when you publish - 1000 entries take ~10 min & 100% cpu.

Comment: I think someone has an overly quick trigger finger on the close link. Surely any question of the format of: "How do I do X within emacs?" or even "blah blah blah emacs" is a programming related question.

Comment: I have nominated it for reopening.

Answer (score 3):

emacspeak has [a module that hooks up to Blogspot](http://emacspeak.blogspot.com/2007/03/emacs-client-for-google-services.html), but I was never able to make it work for editing posts.

Answer (score 2):

[EmacsWikiBlog](http://www.sfu.ca/~gswamina/EmacsWikiBlog.html) may suit your purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You can [accomplish something blog-like](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/?action=browse;oldid=PlannerRecipes;id=PlannerModeMethods#toc7) using [Planner mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PlannerMode).

Answer (score -7):

I don't think emacs is the right tool for this job.

Perhaps you should check out [Blogger](https://www.blogger.com/start) or if you have hosting and want to start a blog maybe try [Wordpress](http://wordpress.org/).

Comment: Um, I don't think you're getting the point here: it's not the blog software, it's using EMACS as a tool to create and post text to a blog.